# Ruby on Rails: how to export a DB to an sql-file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, export, rake

I would like to export the database into a single sql-file. I have taken on a project built by a developer who didn't seem to back it up before leaving the project. I need to take a copy of the database structure so that i can work on it in my local test-environment basically.

I have noticed the `rake db:structure:dump` -command, wich in the terminal gives me the following respons: **rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'dataset:export'**

Is there a gem I need to install or something, or how do you simply export the database into a single file?

Comment: what rails version? what database?

Comment: - ruby: 1.8.7
- rails: 3.2.2
- MySql

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

a) make a rails version of the schema with rake db:schema.dump

The generated file is db/schema.rb
you can load then it locally with db:schema:load

b) use the mysql tools to get real sql dump. See for example

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html

c) try to debug why the rake task fails. a problem may be that you need to set RAILS_ENV first, for example on the Unix-bash with

```
RAILS_ENV=production; export RAILS_ENV
```

But if you do not find a solution fast, try a) or b), because having the database structure is important before changing code, updating gems, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but it didn't work quite as you described it. I already have schema.rb, but how do I turn this into something I can import with MySQLWorkbench? Preferably an sql-file. 'db:schema:load' doesn't work. I'm looking into it, but no results yet.

Comment: Than option b is for you: use command line mysqldump tool. you find the existing database name and user in config/database.yml

Comment: Thank you. I'm sort of new to this way of developing, so I'm still a little confused some times :)